# Git committing creates a file called "-"

Tags: command-line, git, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-12.04

It's very hard to search for on Google with the amount of documentation there is about git, but basically, when I do a "git commit", it creates a file called "-".  It has nothing in it, and is owned by my user.  Is there a reason this file is being created and is there anything I can do to stop it since it's a little annoying?  The file is not under git control.  Git acts like its not even there.

**UPDATE**

As I'm answering questions in the comments, I realized that this happened right after I tried to make it so that I no longer needed to use "ssh-add" every time I wanted to push to a remote.  The following is in my .bash_profile.

```
git() {
      if ! ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>-; then
              ssh-add ~/.ssh/remote1
              ssh-add ~/.ssh/remote2
                fi
                  /usr/bin/git "$@"
}
export -f git
```

If this looks incorrect, let me know.

Comment: Do you just type "`git commit`"? (no parameter at all?)

Comment: At first I was doing "git commit -a", stopped doing that, so yes.  All I'm doing is "git commit".

Comment: Could you try a `git add -A` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add), followed by a `git commit -m "test"` and see if that file '`-`' is still created?

Comment: I removed the file "-" before I began.  I ran "git add -A", I then ran "git commit -m "test".  Git informed me of my branch, commit number, and message.  It took a very long time, I ended it with "control-c".  "Ls"-ed the directory, the magical "-" file had returned.

Comment: Curious! Can you recreate this behavior from a new repo?

Comment: Yes.  Upon any commit my user makes a file called "-" is created.  If I make a commit as sudo, no file is created.  See my updated question for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the part of your command that says `2>-`? That is creating/replacing a file named `-`. What did you mean there? Send STDERR to the same place as STDOUT? The syntax for that is `2>&1`

Comment: Redirecting to `&-` closes that file descriptor in `bash`, e.g. `2>&-`

Comment: That was a straight copy from an Ubuntu help forum post.  Let me change that and see what happens.

Comment: I changed it to "2>&1", seems to have fixed the problem!  Thank you!